# How do I Install fonts on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, installation, web, font

I would like to install Arial on to our web servers. Just need to add, this is because we generate reports server-side and make them available in a number of downloadable formats (Excel, PDF etc), hence the need to have the fonts installed on the server.

I have console access to our webfarm, and from the server I've copied the .ttf files and placed them in c:\fonts folder. Then I run the following VBScript on the server.

```
' VBScript to install fonts on Blade Servers

' Arial font-family

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("c:\fonts")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("arial.ttf")
objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Install")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("c:\fonts")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("arialbd.ttf")
objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Install")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("c:\fonts")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("arialbi.ttf")
objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Install")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("c:\fonts")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("ariali.ttf")
objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Install")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("c:\fonts")
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("ariblk.ttf")
objFolderItem.InvokeVerb("Install")

msgbox "Fonts installed"
```

I get the message box, but no font installation pop-ups like I do when I run this script on my desktop. The fonts do not get installed, they do not sure in the font selection dialogue in notepad (on the web server)  and we get the asp.net exception "Font 'Arial' cannot be found.". Have also restarted the server.

I have also tried copying the .ttf files to the c:\windows\fonts folder and restarting the server.

What do I need to do to install fonts on Windows Web Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I don't know about that specific issue, but would you be open to using PowerShell? It can access the [`AddFontResource `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183326(VS.85).aspx) method

Comment: There's a neat script here: https://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2010/12/04/adding-and-removing-fonts-with-windows-powershell.aspx (although personally I think it's.. overkill, but hey, if it works...)